# Analysing what network connections are made by a service in Linux

Tags: netstat

Is it possible to pipe an executable script through a utility that shows what network connections the script is making [in real time]? I was thinking I might be able to use netstat and connect to that PID, but it doesn't seem to take a PID as an argument (only procotol, int, port etc).

Comment: netstat can show what PID is making connections/listening for connections though. It just can't filter the output that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe netstat with a grep doing the following:

```
sudo netstat -pa | grep "PID/"
```

where PID must be replaced by the PID of your process.

To get real time update, you can use *watch*, for example (with PID=1234):

```
sudo watch -n1 'netstat -pa | grep "1234/"'
```

If you want only network connection and not Linux socket, you can event use:

```
sudo watch -n1 'netstat -ptua | grep "1234/"'
```